# Refresh page div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building a phonegap application using jquery mobile.  I have one page div that displays similar data for each of 10 different steps.  My data is being read in from JSON.  I can correctly incrament the steps by clicking a button, and display this info by using pagebefore show (if I move off the page and then back to it).  But I want the button to refresh (reload) the current page with the new info when I click it.  I can't seem to get it working.  I've tried `location.reload()` and some others with no avail.  Can someone help out a newbie here?

Javascript:

```
var currentStep = 0;  

$.getJSON("rubric.json", function(data) {
    jsonRubric = data;

});

$("#nextStep").on('click', function() {
if (currentStep <9){
currentStep += 1;
location.reload(true);}
});

function setRubricInfo() {
    $('#rubricTitle').html(jsonRubric.rubric[currentStep].title);
    $('#criteria').html(jsonRubric.rubric[currentStep].criteria);
     $('#meets').html(jsonRubric.rubric[currentStep].meets);
     $('#dnmeet').html(jsonRubric.rubric[currentStep].dnmeet);
     $('#exceeds').html(jsonRubric.rubric[currentStep].exceeds);
}
$("#stepOneRubric").on("pagebeforeshow", function(){
setRubricInfo();
});
```

`"#nextStep"` is my button, `"#StepOneRubric"` is my page div.  All the changing of the content happens on pagebeforeshow currently.

HTML:

```
<!-- Step 1 Rubric/page14 -->
<div id="stepOneRubric" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a"> <a class="ui-btn-left" href="#eightStepHome" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext"
          data-icon="arrow-l"> Button </a>
    <h3> Step One Rubric </h3>
  </div>
    <div data-role="content">

  <div align="center">  
  <h4 id="rubricTitle"> sfasfd </h4>
</div>

   <div id=rubricCollapsible data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3> Criteria </h3>
      <p id="criteria"> Critera text</p>
      </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3> Does Not Meet </h3>
        <p id="dnmeet"> Critera text</p>
      </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3> Meets </h3>
        <p id="meets"> Critera text</p>
      </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3> Exceeds </h3>
        <p id="exceeds"> Critera text       
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                </div>
        </div>

      </div>
  </div>
         <a href="#stepOneRubric" id= "nextStep" data-role="button" data-theme="b" > Next 
         </a>
          <div id = "nextStep" a href = "#stepOneRubric" data-role="button" data-theme="b" > Next 
         </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: what is `currentStep`, and where does it take its value from?

Comment: it's a hack but location.href = location.href is forcing a reload (instead of location.reload()), at least on chrome, maybe it helps

Comment: @PitaJ That's not helpful. Provide the **new** method, and a link, if you care to help

Comment: currentStep is just a var decalred at the begining of my code.  It is set to 0 as a default and points to an item in my JSON array.

Comment: That should work. Just for testing, try with `location.reload(true);`. Also, use `.on()` function instead of `.live()`

Comment: @MiljanPuzović Still get forever spinny thing after changing to `.on()` and using `location.reload(true)`

Comment: How do you inject new data into div? what type of data is it?

Comment: @Omar I added some more of my code.

Comment: @c-misura...not sure how to use that...I'll look it up.

Comment: Is the problem that `location.reload` doesn't work? Or, it works, but when the page is reloaded, the data you want to access doesn't exist?

Comment: @c--misura, `location.reload` is not working.  I can force the data to change by navigating to another page and then back.  I just cant get `pagebeforeshow` to fire using the next button.

Comment: You have another problem, duplicated **id** `nextStep`. Use unique ids always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.trigger('create')` after appending new items into `[data-role=page]`. This will re-enhance the markup of your code as you're using `.html()`.

There is no need to `refresh` or reload the page. However, if you want to give the *feeling* that the page is being refreshed, you can reload the same page using `$.mobile.changePage()` with option `allowSamePageTransition: true`.

[Check this example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/MLX6X/)

```
var currentStep = 0;
$("#nextStep").on('click', function() {
 if (currentStep <9){
  currentStep++;
  setRubricInfo();
 }
 $('[data-role=page]').trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: How does `currentStep` get incremented here, it's inside the `if` statement

Comment: `var currentStep` is outside the `if` @c--misura check the example in my answer.

Comment: But it's being increment inside the `if` statement @Omar

Comment: it needs to be increased one step until its' value is 9. @c--misura

Comment: @Omar YES!  This is exactly what I wanted, it works perfectly.  Thank you!  And my incramenting is in the right spot, otherwise clicking the button repeatedly could run the var up past the number of items in my array causing problems.

Comment: @LisaCoxSparksParker You're welcome :) side note: use unique **id** for elements. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What version of jQuery?  `.live()` is deprecated.

*"As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. 
 Use .on() to attach event handlers. 
 Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."*

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Use `.on()` instead.

```
$("#stepOneRubic").on('click', '#nextStep', function() {
    if (currentStep <9){
        currentStep += 1;}
    location.reload();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you, I should have know this, I've used it before.  But it doesn't fix my problem.  It just hangs and gives me the forever spinny animation.

Comment: This isn't the equivalent of `live`. This is normal event handling. You need to use event delegation, like `$("#container_id").on("click", ".element-class", function () { });`